# How to find the path of webapps directory using java

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there some way to find the path of tomcat's webapps directory using java, as we use `System.getProperties("...")`  to get `user.dir` etc

thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah! put that dir string in -D tomcat opts and then getThatProperty();

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `System.getProperty( "catalina.base" )`  for same. And add `"/webapps"` to path.

Comment: Pls refer to modified post